# React-Native Select List Overley

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

If I have a component/container form that allows a user to select a group, I am not hip to what the component/ux should be for this, but I would imagine a select list overlay type deal, am I wrong in assuming this? Why is this not available in the react-native core? The picker for android offers this, but it seems like the iOS version is just the slot machine style picker. Am I missing something?

Is the Picker only the slot machine on iOS or is there a way without bringing in a third party component to provide this functionality for both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you understand that React Native is not hybrid application like phone-gap. React Native actually pulls out the native controls off of operating system. That is why, you are seeing slot-machine like picker in iOS and material-style picker in Android.

What you need to grok is that React Native is not meant to build cross-platform applications with "same" codebase. The codebase will change a little bit depending upon the OS.

You'll want to keep your business logic separate from the UI components or views, so that you can reuse the business logic in Android and iOS. UI components will differ for obvious reasons. For eg. You will not need Android Toolbar in iOS application, because there is no such thing as toolbar available natively in iOS. Similarly you will not find NavigationBarIOS in Android.

Bottom line- keep your UI components separately in a "components" folder. You can pull out desired components from "components" folders depending upon the OS.

For reference, please go through this. This is my example project back from the days when I was learning react-native. So do expect it to be very amateur-level code. [Repo](https://github.com/KarandikarMihir/explore-movies). You can see how I have kept things separately. Good luck!

Comment: You have reminded me of some good points. Thanks for the input.